# Как подключить все файлы из папки?

Tags: php

Можно, без считывания циклов из директории всех файлов, подключить все файлы?

Увидел функцию `set_include_path()`, только не вижу примеров ее использования.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласен с первым ответом, но если уж очень хочется, то надо писать свою функцию:

```
   $dir = "наш каталог";  
   $catalog = opendir($dir);

   while ($filename = readdir($catalog )) // перебираем наш каталог 
   {  
      $filename = $dir."/".$filename;  
      include_once($filename); // один раз подрубаем, чтоб не повторяться 
   }

   closedir($catalog);
```

хорошо бы еще добавить проверку на - файл это или каталог, что это за файл и прочее.

Comment: http://www.php.su/functions/?file-exists

Comment: эту функцию можно здесь не использовать. Лучше обратиться к функциям is_dir() и is_file() - они выявят файл это или каталог и соответственно существует ли он

Comment: Благодарен

Comment: почему не glob?

Comment: Как сказано в официальной документации - эта функция не прокатывает на некоторых Осях, не применима к удаленным файлам, и тд. Лучше уж что-то понадежнее

Answer (score 2):

[set_include_path](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-include-path.php) - Устанавливает значение настройки конфигурации include_path

Эта функция не для твоей задачи. Да и небезопасно инклудить то, что явно не прописано в скриптах.

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще вот так с проверкой

```
$files = scandir($dir);   
foreach($files as $file){  
    if(($file !== '.') AND ($file !== '..'))
    include_once $dir .DS. $file;
```